# How do I open a folder or file using the editor from Terminal on OS X?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sudo

I love Ubuntu, and I used it for a long time before Unity. I loved it. Now I have a Mac...

I have some habits remaining from my Ubuntu workflow.

Sometimes I like to open folders from terminal directly, on Ubuntu I would do `gksudo gnome-open /folder` or open files for editing in my favorite editor `sudo gedit /file.php`

So how is it done on OS X?

I use Sublime Text 2 as my main editor, so is it possible to use Sublime like gedit from terminal?

P.S.: Quick Google search found me `open .` for opening folders. But will sudo work like gksudo on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will sudo work like gksudo on Ubuntu?

No, it won't. To open the folder you're currently in, all you really need to do is type `open .`. If you want to open a file, the same applies.

If you however need root permissions for a file, then you need to tell `open` which application exactly to run. Normally, you would do this with `open -a NameOfApplication`, like `open -a TextEdit`, but TextEdit will still be run without root privileges if you call `sudo open -a TextEdit`. This is because the process of opening is deferred from `open` to a service in OS X that won't run as root.

The trick is to run the actual executable of the application you want to open with `sudo`. For example:

> `sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /path/to/file`

If you're lazy and want to repeat doing that, you could create [an alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) in your shell.

---

> is it possible to use Sublime like gedit from terminal?

Much easier:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

That requires `~/bin/subl` to be in your `PATH`. Otherwise:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

Then just run `subl /path/to/file`.